# Setup Google Analytics Goals with user session properties

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, metrics, product-management

I’m trying to set up some dashboard to track the page views of my customers and identify how many of them visit the website logged in, how many visit the website and have a plan subscribed (SaaS company) and how many visit a specific page and have a plan subscribed.

Is there a way to implement this in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send these informations to Google Analytics (i.e. an event when user is logged) you can create segments and get them number.

You can find here how to build a new segment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en

Comment: Do you have any tutorial link or some term that I can search google for? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added a link to the answer